# iOS - Custom presentation controller doesn't update the presented navigationBar height appropriately for split view

Tags: ios, ipad

I have created my own subclass of `UIPresentationController` and I am presenting a navigation controller using it. The purpose is to somewhat mimic the behavior of UIPopoverPresentationController but allow for more customization.

So the problem I am experiencing is that on iPad when the user adjusts the size of the app using splitview, the navigation bar's height doesn't update correctly.

When the view is in a popover style it is supposed to use a height of 44 for the nav bar and when it is in fullscreen style it uses a height of 64. This is happening correctly upon first presenting the controller. However if the user adjusts the app using splitview the nav bar height does not update at all.

In my `UIPresentationController` subclass I am doing the following:

I set the frame based on the container view's width:

```
override func frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView() -> CGRect {
    if let containerView = containerView {
        if containerView.bounds.width > 500 {

            let preferredSize = presentedViewController.preferredContentSize
            return CGRect(x: containerView.bounds.width - preferredSize.width - 20, y: 16, width: preferredSize.width, height: preferredSize.height)

        } else {
            return containerView.bounds
        }
    } else {
        return CGRectZero
    }
}
```

Then I update the frame whenever I get the willLayoutSubviews call:

```
override func containerViewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    presentedViewController.view.frame = frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView()
}
```

When I examine the presentedViewController's view, it is getting all the correct values and visually is the right size. The **only** problem is that the nav bar will remain the height that it was originally presented at (whether that is 44 or 64) and will either leave a gap or extend passed its bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I found a solution that works. Inside my `containerViewWillLayoutSubviews` function I simply access the navigation controller's `navigationBar` property and manually set its frame correctly.

```
        if let navigationController = presentedViewController as? UINavigationController {
            navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                                              y: 0,
                                                              width: presentedViewController.view.frame.size.width,
                                                              height: containerView.bounds.width > 500 ? 44 : 64)
        }
```

This does seem a bit fragile though, but its working fine for me.